# ¿Como puedo descomprimir un archivo .zip de un contenedor azure blod?

Tags: azure

Tengo una archivo .zip en azure blod que pesa aproximadamente 6GB y necesito descomprimirlo dentro del contenedor para poder trabajar con su contenido pero no encuentro manera para hacerlo, desconozco si esto es posible, mi otra opción es subir un folder descomprimido desde el computador pero tampoco encuentro una opción para ello, por que solo me deja seleccionar un archivo especifico y no una carpeta completa, de antemano gracias!!

Comment: Mejor usa File share y sube el contenido de tu folder.

Comment: No es posible dentro del storaga account, pero hay varias formas de hacerlo:  con adf o con una azure function

Comment: Puedes crear una azure function donde el trigger sea cada vez que un archivo zip se crea en tu container... y que descarge, descomprima y vuelva a subir todo al storage, asi automaticamente cada vez que insertes un zip en el storage este sera descomprimido

Comment: Con ADF tendrias que crear un pipeline, el trigger seria el mismo cada vez que un zip, el proceso no se exactamente como pero parece que podrias copiar a un zip a un data lake... se ve mas complejo que hacerlo simplemente con c# utilizando una azure function